# Register a Dll in LOCAL_MACHINE

Tags: c++, com, registry

I want to register my Dll to specific path in registry and not in default path that it takes usually.. I am new to Windows and doesnt know much about it. Can any one tell me what all things i need to mention in my code piece or is there anything that can be added to it so that my dll get registers in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

Comment: dlls are usually not registered. Are you talking about COM?

Comment: Please clarify what problem you need to solve. Default COM registration via `regsvr32` usually registers COM server in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` that is actually alias for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes`

Comment: I want to create a subkey under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (eg:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\ALGORITHM) and futhur i want to register my COM Dll into HLM hierarchy as mentioned above.

Comment: @user1670518: That's not how it works. You can create that key for _additional_ information, but the COM registration must be in either `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to do that? COM dlls must be registered at HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, anything else makes no sense.

The reason is that when some other component needs to instantiate your COM server, they will typically call `CoCreateInstance` API which will lookup the class info in the HKCR hive of the registry and not somewhere else. If you would register your class somewhere else no other component would be able to find it which would be the same as if it was not registered at all.

Comment: I want to do this for application which will b used by my organization and not the others. i want to register all Dll to Specified path .. What functionality i need to add to DllRegisterServer() so that my Dll goes to exact location as specified.

Comment: How do you expect other components to find your component?

Comment: I am basically developing the framework which will have Inreface lib and algorithm Lib. ANy code added to Algorithm dll get registers at location specified.

Comment: I understand that. But in COM, other components instantiate the dependencies via APIs that expect to find stuff in HKCR. If you change the location, it is the same as if they are not registered at all, so you don't need to do anything. How exactly will you create an instance of your COM component?

Comment: `HKCR` [is primarily intended for compatibility with the registry in 16-bit Windows.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724475(v=vs.85).aspx). `HKLM` is the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Win32 API Registry functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms724875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

1. Create (open if exists) key with [`RegCreateKeyEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms724844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
2. Set value with [`RegSetValueEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms724923%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
3. Close registry key with [`RegCloseKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms724837%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

See also [some sample code](http://www.functionx.com/visualc/articles/regvalues.htm).

Comment: But that will only create subkey using above registry function..What function are needed to be used so that my Dll get regsiter in the key created with above registry function?

Comment: If you think you could register your DLL in any registry key and `CoCreateInstance` then will find and load it as usual you will fail. Standard COM API is aware only about `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes` registrations. You must write your own COM object loading/creating function which definitely is not a piece of cake. Still don't understand why do you need it?

Comment: Okay.I have one more query to this.Are the Dll generated by Visual studio are COM DLL? I want to register the Dll given by Visual studio

Comment: @user1670518 It depends of project type. If the project created as e.g. ATL Server or MFC ActiveX yes, it's COM. If project created as Win32 DLL, no, it's not COM (unless all COM support written manually).

Comment: Okay..So here now i have a project created as Win32 Dll..can i register this Dll to any specific path i want to ?

Comment: @user1670518 Simple Win32 DLLs don't require any registration. They can be loaded by file name and used as is.

Comment: How can i see my registered Dll entry into hierarchy i create? No matter whereever it get registered using Regsvr32. All i want is to see my DLL entry into the apth i create using RegCreateKeyEx.

Comment: Manually - use `regedit.exe` utility. Programmatically - use [`RegEnumKeyEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms724862(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`RegEnumValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms724865(v=vs.85).aspx) Win32 API functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clarify what you mean by "register".

COM is a specification, and if you want to register your component for COM, you need to follow the spec. That means `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes`. It doesn't make sense to register a COM server anywhere else, because nothing will find it.

If you mean something else by "register" then please clarify.

Comment: Register - Registering/Unregistering the Dll using Regsvr32.

Comment: Regsvr32 doesn't do anything special - it only calls `DllRegisterServer` in the DLL. The point is that nothing will be able to *use* your DLL if it's not registered properly. Why don't you want to use normal COM registration?